# Limiting sum of a tan sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series

The sequence is:
$1 - tan^{2}x + tan^{4}x ...$ With the values of the limiting sum $x$ exists in the interval $-π/2 < x < π/2$. How do I find the values of $x$?

I saw someone use this method online:
$ \left|r\right|< 1 \rightarrow \left|-tan^{2}x\right|< 1 \to tan^{2}x < 1 \to -1 < tanx < 1 \to -π/4 < x < π/4$

What I dont understand is how by square rooting the equality to make tan squared tan that there is a negative one on the left side and not just $tanx < 1$ and $tanx < -1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More generally, if $a^2 \le b^2$, then
$|a| \le |b|$.  If $a$ is a real number, that says $-|b| \le a \le |b|$.